# Discrete Mathematics ordered pairs and equivalence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

a) Given a set $S$ with the $n$ elements, find the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$ such that

i) $A \subseteq B \subseteq S$

ii) $A \subset B \subseteq S$

b) Let n be a positive integer and S a set of size n. How many relations $\approx$ on S are there that are:

i. an equivalence relation and a partial ordering?

ii. an equivalence relation and a total ordering?

Normally the topic that I ask about I have a general understanding of (Calculus) but I am having a really tough time with Discrete Maths... Any idea what I should do here?

Comment: These are two separate questions with nothing to do with one another and should have been asked separately.  That said, they have both been asked on this site multiple times already.

Comment: Does this answer your first question? [How many pairs are in $(B,C)\in\mathcal{P}(A)\times \mathcal{P}(A)$ such that $B\subseteq C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636192/how-many-pairs-are-in-b-c-in-pa-times-pa-such-that-b-subseteq-c).  Does this answer your second question? [Find total number of relations that are equivalence as well as partial order set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803299/find-total-number-of-relations-that-are-equivalence-as-well-as-partial-order-set)

Comment: For hints in part 2 of each problem, a2: how many of what you counted in a1 are "bad" did we not want to count in part 2?  For b2: knowing what we know for part 1, can there possibly be a total ordering that is also an equivalence relation for $n>1$?  For completions sake, what about for $n=0$ and for $n=1$

Comment: Thank you for answer to question number two and for question one I guess I found a better link but I still don't completely understand it...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163130/counting-the-ordered-pairs-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-subsets-of-s-and-a

Comment: What is not to understand?  For (a1) we count by direct multiplication principle.  For each of the $n$ elements in $S$, exactly one of three things must be true: The element is in all three of $A,B,S$, or the element is not in $A$ but is in $B$ and $S$, or the element is not in $A$ and not in $B$ but is in $S$.  There are $3$ choices for each of the $n$ elements giving $3\times 3\times 3\times \cdots \times 3 = 3^n$ possible overall scenarios.  For (a2), of these $3^n$ scenarios, the number who are "bad" and we didn't want to count are those where $A=B$, similar logic shows $2^n$ were bad...

Comment: ...giving a corrected count for (a2) as the amount we counted from (a1) minus the amount that were bad for a total of $3^n-2^n$